# How do you manage "network locations" through domain group policies?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I know how to map network drives through GPOs, but I would like to map a "network location":

[image]

I know how to add those on the workstation itself through Windows Explorer:

[image]

But I don't know how to add/remove them through GPOs.

Comment: I've tried to find an answer for this myself, and came up empty, so let us know if you find something.  I've even used procmon to capture file/reg changes.

Comment: @BretFisher: Oh wow, that really puts my hopes down :( I hoped that there is a built-in approach. For this task at hand I really wouldn't want to roll anything from scratch, mapped network drives are actually an option. I'll look into it though, as this seems like a much more elegant approach. If you don't mind, I'd love to have a look at whatever procmon results you'd want to share. My email is in my profile :)

Comment: If you are willing to do drive mappings life is good! Use Group Policy Preferences (shown as Preferences in gpo edit mmc) to map drives.  Personally I feel the drive mapping concept is legacy but we've got no great alternative for network file share access yet... so map away.  Other then only having ~20 letters for mappings, there's no real down side to drive mappings. Preferences let's you map drives on all sorts of if/elseif statements including group membership, any value in AD, or just about any attribute of a machine. What's your reason for wanting network location over drive mappings?

Comment: @BretFisher: Just as you said. It *felt* legacy and I wanted to see if there are other options. This looked like a much better approach. The concept of drive letters seemed unnecessary, and the drive letter that would fit this network location *just perfectly* is always already taken by another assignment :D Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @BretFisher Turns out it's simply a folder which contents are displayed in that area. You can place anything you want there. Just have a look at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created the function below to accomplish the very same thing. You can include it as a part of a login script. The usage is as follows:

```powershell
New-NetworkShortcut -Name 'New Network Shortcut' -Target '\\server\share\path'
```

```powershell
function New-NetworkShortcut()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Target
    )

    $networkshortcut_name = $Name
    $networkshortcut_target = $Target

    $networkshortcuts_path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('NetworkShortcuts')

    $networkshortcut_path = "$networkshortcuts_path\$networkshortcut_name"
    $desktopini_path = "$networkshortcut_path\desktop.ini"
    $targetlnk_path = "$networkshortcut_path\target.lnk"

    $desktopini_text = "[.ShellClassInfo]`r`nCLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}`r`nFlags=2"

    if( Test-Path -Path $networkshortcut_path -PathType Container )
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $networkshortcut_path -Recurse -Force
    }

    [void](New-Item -Path $networkshortcut_path -ItemType directory)

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $networkshortcut_path -Name Attributes -Value 1

    Out-File -FilePath $desktopini_path -InputObject $desktopini_text -Encoding ascii

    Set-ItemProperty -Path $desktopini_path -Name Attributes -Value 6

    $WshShell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($targetlnk_path)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $networkshortcut_target
    $Shortcut.Save()
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the 1year delay ;) This works great and it also made me realize what the underlying concept of these network locations is. I wasn't aware that it is simply a folder into which you can place arbitrary shortcuts. This is pretty awesome.

Comment: No problem, I can't believe that was a whole year ago. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

You can actually map the shortcut using Group Policy.

Using **Server 2012 R2** *Essentials*, I mapped a **WebDAV** folder from our companies **SharePoint Online** site.

---

In *Group Policy Management Editor*:

1. Go to 'User Configuration/Preferences/Windows Settings/Shortcuts'
2. **Right click** in the list of shortcuts then click '**Shortcut**'
3. Use the following settings

*Settings:*

- **Target Type** = File System Object
- **Location** = My Network Places
- **Target Path** = \\CONTOSO.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER
- For target path, replace **CONTOSO** with your company's sub-domain.
- In our case, FOLDER was a Team Site in the root directory and SUBFOLDER was the document library that we wanted to map.

---

**Notes:**

- This should also work with **Computer Configuration**, but I didn't test it.
- This should also work with other types of shares, but I didn't test it.